# Export report through command with filter options or more fileds

Tags: coverity

I'm using coverity 8.1. I run the following command to export the coverity report as csv file through command.

```
/opt/cov-analysis-linux64-8.1.0/bin/cov-manage-im --mode defects --show --stream $cov_stream_cpp --stream $cov_stream_java --host $cov_server --port $cov_port --auth-key-file $cov_auth_file --fields cid,file > ~/Coverity.csv
```

Is there anyway I can filter the report by Impact? I want to export by High/Medium/Low.

I don't find any option. I also tried to get all fields, but it supports only **`action, checker, cid, classification, component, ext-ref, file, function, legacy, owner, severity, status, stream-name`** and nothing else. I wanted to get the Impact also.

How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the command:

```
$ cov-manage-im  --mode defects --show --auth-key-file $auth --host $host --port $port --output fields
            action
            cid
            checker
            classification
            component
            ext-ref
            file
            function
            owner
            severity
            status
            legacy
            stream-name     (stream scope only)
```

doesn't list the field you want; as far as i can tell you are out of luck